# i want to send variable from one php page to another using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Page 1 js:**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn").on("click", function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./page.php",
        data: { name: "peter" },
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
        },
      });
    });
  });
```

**Page 2 php:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $name =$_GET['name'];
    echo $name;
}
else{
    echo "data not recived";
}


?>
```

*Here, at the first page it triggers the alert and displays the value
of "name" but it doesn't return the value to the destination url and
it executes the else statement. 
Thanks for your help!*

Comment: what do you see in your browser dev tools ?

Comment: maybe using jquery for a simple redirection is way too complicated here. A simple `window.location = page.php?name=peter` would be enough, set in the button onclick... could be dynamic if required (don't forget to urlencode the name value)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to leave comment.
I tested your code, and your code is correct. I don't know why you cannot get your expected result. But I think you can try the go to 
http://localhost/page.php?name=aaa in your browser
to see it will show "aaa" or "data not recived"